# Is there a term for individuals who can "visualize" numbers and advanced mathematics?

Tags: terminology, intelligence, problem-solving, mathematical-ability

I recently saw [an episode of 60 Minutes about Jacob Barnett](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-504803_162-57359443-10391709/jake-hanging-out-with-a-teenage-einstein/), a 13 year old boy who is currently attending advanced physics classes at a local university and was portrayed by the show as being a child prodigy/genius. In the interview, he demonstrates how he's able to perform mathematical transformations in his head by visualizing the numbers as colored shapes. As he explains in the linked clip:

> This is `2 * 27`:
>   [image: This is 2x27]

He visualizes multiplying 2 by 27 as a series of colored triangles.

Is this a known phenomenon, and if so, does it have a name? Do other individuals visualize mathematics like this? Or is this just a 12-year old kid... embellishing (to be polite) his thought process?

Comment: As background context, there is a more general literature on the important role of visualisation in learning mathematics.
A [Google Scholar search for "visualisation in learning mathematics"](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&q=visualisation+in+mathematics+learning&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=&as_vis=0) yields  many interesting articles including [this](http://cimm.ucr.ac.cr/ojs/index.php/eudoxus/article/viewFile/154/152)
and [this](http://www.kaputcenter.umassd.edu/downloads/symcog/bib/pmeVisualizationFinalAPA.pdf).

Comment: I can "see" some numbers as colors.. though It looks like the correct term is synesthesia, I've never heard of it..

Comment: Arent they all generally just called Savants?

Comment: @abhiii5459 not really. "Savant" would be a good description of Jacob Barnett, but I was wondering if other individuals visualize mathematics like he described. They don't have to be savants. Also, the term "savant" isn't specific to visualizing numbers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like a form of [Synesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia), in particular it sounds like [Number Form Synesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_form) mixed with [Grapheme-color Synesthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme%E2%80%93color_synesthesia):

> A number form is a mental map of numbers, which automatically and involuntarily appears whenever someone who experiences number-forms thinks of numbers. Number forms were first documented and named by Francis Galton in "The Visions of Sane Persons". Later research has identified them as a type of synesthesia. In particular, it has been suggested that number-forms are a result of "cross-activation" between regions of the parietal lobe that are involved in numerical cognition and spatial cognition

It doesn't seem exactly like what he does but it could be a form of it. It's hard to imagine just how it would be to perceive the world as a synesthesic person does.

It sounds like he's learned to apply his visual-spatial skills to "arrange" the number forms to aid his calculations.

Synesthesia is covered in detail in the book [Synesthesia: a union of the senses](http://books.google.com/books?id=fl6wX4xzb_kC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), though I'm not aware of any specific case studies on individuals with this exact set of skills.

A term to describe people with Synestesia is **Synesthesic**.

Comment: Wow, that's fascinating. It's also really interesting that you state *It sounds like he's learned to apply his visual-spatial skills to "arrange" the number forms to aid his calculations* because this occurred to me after hearing him explain. I thought, *Hmm, this sounds like how a GPU can perform certain tasks much better than a CPU!*

Comment: Reading Wikipedia further, it appears that [Richard Feynman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman) had Synesthesia. He may not have all the same skills as Jacob, but given that he was a Nobel prize winner, he was clearly a very intelligent man!